# Is It possible have custom pop-up menu for more than one mailItems in NetOffice

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, netoffice

My custom pop-up context menu run only for selection of one mail in my mail-list. Is there posibily to run for more than one mail selection?

```
<contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuMailItem">
  <menu id="customID" label="CustomPrg" getImage="logo_image2">
    <button id="btn1" onAction="TransferBtns_Click" getLabel="ArchiveLabel" imageMso="CopyToFolder"/>          
    <button id="btn2" onAction="AchivetoBtn_Click" getLabel="ArchiveLabelOp"  imageMso="CopyToFolder"/>
    <menuSeparator id="separatormnu"/>
    <splitButton id="btn3">
</contextMenu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<contextMenus>    
  <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuMultipleItems">
    <button id="MyContextMenuMultipleItems"
        label="ContextMenuMultipleItems"
        onAction="OnMyButtonClick"/>
  </contextMenu>  
</contextMenus>
```

[view this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172(v=office.14).aspx#OfficeOLExtendingUI_ContextMenuforMultipleSelectedItems)